# How can i specify where o board ends?

Tags: java

i have a board([17][17]) and i place words in it giving the row and the column.I want if the position of the word given is bigger than the board,then a message is shown and you should give the row and column again.

```
 **Board class**
  ......
  public void placeWord(char[][] board, String word, int x, int y)

for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
     if (y + i >= board[x].length)
         {
             System.out.println("The board is smaller!!");
              Board b=new Board();
              int a,r;
              System.out.println("Give row and column again");
              a=in.nextInt();
              r=in.nextInt();
              b.placeWord(board, word, a, r);
         }

     else {
         board[x][y + i] = word.charAt(i);
         }
    }
```

When i give a=3 and r=5 it still prints me "The board is smaller!!" and want to give new values again.Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit**

```
 **main()**
 board b=new board();
 String s="abc";
 int x=2,y=20;
 b.placeWord(Board, s, x, y);

 for(int i=0;i<Board.length;i++)//prints the board
     {
          System.out.println(Board[i]);

         }
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify a little bit.  I've been looking at this for a few minutes and I can't parse what you're asking.  An example call and return value would be nice.

Comment: Making a new `Board`, then calling `placeWord` in the middle of the `placeWord` method can't be helping.

Comment: Check to see if the word fits before you enter the loop, and only enter the loop once you know the word will fit.

Comment: @nick In you edit there is a mixture of upper and lowercase identifiers and thus it will not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `a=3 and r=5` I suspect you already failed for placing the word in the first place and entered a new row/column.

In this case the "old" for loop has not finished yet and will continue to place letters (as long as there are some remaining) after the call to `b.placeWord(...);`.

One way to circumvent this is to break the loop by a simple `break;` statement after the call to `b.placeWord(...);`.

Note: the second time you are filling the word into your newly created board `b` which you discard afterwards (it is never accessed anywhere in the code you showed us). Additionally you might first *test* if the word fits (can actually be done without a loop: `y+word.length()<=board[x].length()`) and then fill in the letters. Otherwise the remainders of the failed attempt will stay on the board.

Comment: Yes you right this with break worded!!And you are right i should test firts if the word fits....but where i right this"y+word.length()<=board[x].length()"?outside for?

Comment: @nick Yes, you should place it outside the loop (such that it is checked only once).

Answer (score 0):

```
 **Board class**
  ......
  public void placeWord(char[][] board, String word, int x, int y)
    if (y + word.length() >= board[x].length)
    {
       // don't loop, ask for another position to put word
       System.out.println("The board is smaller!!");
       Board b=new Board();
       int a,r;
       System.out.println("Give row and column again");
       a=in.nextInt();
       r=in.nextInt();
       b.placeWord(board, word, a, r);
    } else
    {
      // already done the checking, don't need to worry here
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
      {
         board[x][y + i] = word.charAt(i);
      }
    }
```